# какая сетка используется на сайте

Tags: jquery, css, вёрстка, scss

Всем привет)

Заказчик хочет сделать похожую сетку на сайте, как здесь: http://secretmag.ru/, но никак не могу понять, как она реализована. Посмотрела html, сначала выводятся большие блоки, потом средние, потом те, что с иконками серыми.  Судя по css все блоки с абсолютной позицией, и для каждого прописаны координаты, но что-то не верится, что это все сделано вручную...

Может кто знает, какой плагин там использован? 
Или может это какой-то специальный css-фреймворк?

Буду очень благодарна за помощь!!! :)

Comment: На мобильном выглядит как обычно. Могу предположить что на сервере обрабатывают размеры экрана и генерируют, а потом благодаря кешу ускоряют загрузку последующих страниц

Comment: _но что-то не верится, что это все сделано вручную_ - в любом css препроцессоре доступны циклы, поэтому не обязательно расписывать все медиа запросы вручную

Comment: Да, скорее всего через препроцессор, только я логику совершенно уловить не могу, особенно для средних блоков, которые мнения и тд

Comment: Есть тут некая цикличность, но она мне пока не ясна. Это нужно сидеть и разбирать

Comment: размеры блоков фиксированы - осталось просто расположить их

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет.
Вот что используется на этом сайте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел расширением для Google Chrome `Wappalyzer`